# Cannot get URL (with sql query) to be handled by DefaultHttpClient in java

Tags: java, android, sql, http

I've been struggling for half a day trying to learn this and am stuck. My goal is to query finance data from yql yahoo finance tables. I have set up some code from an AndroidHive example and am able to get it running correctly for their sample query. But that sample query just grabs a JSON object directly from the main URL that they provide. To do this for yql, I need to convert the SQL query into a format that the httpClient will recognize, and my app keeps hanging and never returning a response.

First, I tried taking the exact query string from the yql to replicate their search, which for me was this:

https://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20symbol%2CChange%20from%20yahoo.finance.quote%20where%20symbol%20in%20(%22SH%22%2C%22DOG%22%2C%22RWM%22)&format=json&env=store%3A%2F%2Fdatatables.org%2Falltableswithkeys&callback=

That gives me a null result when I set url = to the above, and then run the following:

```
DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
.
.
.
HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);    
httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpGet);
```

If I do this with the AndroidHive example URL in my code, it works fine.
If I enter the above URL in browser, it works fine. So clearly, my URL is not being entered correctly.

So then I read online that I need to use a URLEncode to convert syntax of URL into the correct format. Here's what I did:

```
private String url = "https://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=" +URLEncoder.encode("select symbol, Change from yahoo.finance.quote where symbol in (\"SH\",\"DOG\".\"RWM\")")+"&format=json&env=store%3A%2F%2Fdatatables.org%2Falltableswithkeys&callback=";
```

That gives me 2 problems. First, it tells me that encode is deprecated, and that I am supposed to use the new syntax that adds a "UTF-8" as a second string parameter, but when I do that, it is a compiler error of java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException (ugh), so then I just tried running it with the deprecated form, but that just leaves my app hanging forever like the original format.

I must be doing something really obvious incorrect here...

---

okay - updated.

HTTPS!!! versus HTTP. the sample query that i did for the AndroidHive example was HTTP and this yql query had HTTPS. if i simply change it to HTTP it works, and i didn't even need to do the URLEncoder business. The string directly from yql worked.

Now I need to start solving my JSON parsing bugs, but I've got my data!

Comment: (\"SH\",\"DOG\".\"RWM\")") - There is a '.' character after "DOG" instead of a ',' character in the query you have posted. Try changing that and see if it works

Comment: Thanks @PrahaladDeshpande -- that would have also been a problem :) When I realized that I was making an HTTPS call instead of an HTTP call, I fixed that and ended up copying the original query string from the yql site. So I didn't have the "." character in there. I'm good-to-go now.